# Перестали отображаться стили 1С-Битрикс

Tags: php, битрикс

Редактировал файл `header.php`, сохранил и на сайте началась вот такая ерунда (http://www.verbnyi.ru/contacts/). Стили и js-файлы перестали грузиться, отменил изменения в файле `header.php`, проблема все равно осталась.

Как быть?

```
 <?$APPLICATION->ShowPanel();?> 
<!--header-->

<div class="i-header"> <header class="b-header"> <a class="b-header__logo" href="/" ></a> <? 
$hh=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if ($hh=='/bron/m2/bron.php'){
echo '<div class="icoxsl"><a id="bxid_986036" href="/upload/reestr-m5-2.xlsx" title="Реестр свободных квартир" ></a><br/>Реестр свободных квартир<br/><span>(15.04.2014)</span></div>';
}
elseif ($hh=='/bron/bron.php'){
echo '<div class="icoxsl"><a id="bxid_735836" href="/upload/reestr-m5-3.xlsx" title="Реестр свободных квартир" ></a><br/>Реестр свободных квартир<br/><span>(15.04.2014)</span></div>';
}
elseif ($hh=='/bron/m3/bron.php'){
echo '<div class="icoxsl"><a id="bxid_997561" href="/upload/reestr-m5-1.xlsx" title="Реестр свободных квартир" ></a><br/>Реестр свободных квартир<br/><span>(15.04.2014)</span></div>';
}
?>          <?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
    "bitrix:menu",
    "template1",
    Array(
        "ROOT_MENU_TYPE" => "top",
        "MAX_LEVEL" => "1",
        "USE_EXT" => "N",
        "MENU_CACHE_TYPE" => "A",
        "MENU_CACHE_TIME" => "3600",
        "MENU_CACHE_USE_GROUPS" => "N",
        "MENU_CACHE_GET_VARS" => ""
    )
);?>                 </header> </div>

<div class="i-container"> <? 
$hh=explode('/',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
if ($hh[1]=='about')
{
echo '<div style="min-height:600px;" class="b-main b-main_bg" role="main">';

}

 else
{
echo '<div style="min-height:800px;"  class="b-main" role="main">';
}

?> 
  <h1 class="b-main__title"><?$APPLICATION->ShowTitle(false);?></h1>
 <?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
    "bitrix:main.include",
    "",
    Array(
        "AREA_FILE_SHOW" => "file",
        "PATH" => "/include/tel.php",
        "EDIT_TEMPLATE" => ""
    )
);?></div>
```

Comment: Их даже в коде не видно, поэтому и не грузятся. Киньте код файла, посмотрим.

Comment: @mountpoint обновил первый пост.

Comment: А что между тегами head творится?

Comment: @mountpoint понятия не имею, а что должно?

Comment: Судя по коду, его вообще нет: http://joxi.ru/GrqVgpZfGxXPmz

Comment: @mountpoint раньше все тоже самое стояло, стоило отредактировать файл в админке - все слетело.

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос решен: как сказал [@mountpoint](/users/13008/mountpoint) , отсутствовала часть <head></head>.
Видимо, после сохранения файла во внутреннем редакторе, он его тупо вырезал. Вставил, все заработало.

Comment: ну вот и славненько